# Pass parameters from html/thymeleaf to spring controller on button click

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

`Thymeleaf` newbie here. I have an input field in my html / thymeleaf page, the contents of this field I want to send to a spring controller (`/checkStock`) when the user clicks confirm button.

I'm using `onclick` and `window.location.href = '@{/checkstock}'` to call the spring controller but cannot work out how to pass the contents of the field to the spring controller.

Spring Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/checkStock")
@ResponseBody
public String checkStock(@PathVariable String stockId) {
    // want to use stockId here
}
```

`localhost:8080/checkStock?stockId=1234` // 1234 to come from the html page.

How in Thymeleaf can I call the above Spring controller with the parameter? Is it something along the lines of:

```
<button th:onclick="'window.location.href=\'/checkstock?stockId=' + ${id} + '\''">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your controller code like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/checkstock")
@ResponseBody
public String checkStock(@RequestParam String stockId) {
    // ...
}
```

I can list the mistakes as follows:

- You are calling the `/checkstock` url, but you typed it as `checkStock`.
- You are sending `@RequestParam`, but you typed it as `@PathVariable`.